# How to use following simple query in code igniter format?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
SET @rownum:=0;
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as count, student_name,student_info FROM studnet;
```

I want to merge this query in code igniter model...

I want output as follows where count is dynamic i.e. increases as record increases :::

```
count  student_name  student_info
1        Ram          Palpa
2        Shyam        Butwal
```

Comment: Try adding your variable initialization part  in join ex `SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as count, student_name,student_info FROM studnet JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0)tmp;`

Answer (score 0):

Using 
[CodeIgniter's Database Custom Function Calls](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/call_function.html):

Assuming you have **mysqli** set in your *application/config/database.php*:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Then in your model:

```
$this->load->database();

// Perform a mysqli_multi_query
$db_id = $this->db->conn_id;
$this->db->call_function("multi_query", $db_id, "SET @rownum:=0; SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as count, student_name,student_info FROM student;"
$this->db->call_function('next_result', $db_id);  // Skip the first query in this multi_query since you want the result from the second query
$result = $this->db->call_function("store_result", $db_id);

// Output each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $row['count'] . " ". $row['student_name'] . " " . $row['student_info'] . "\n";
}
```